# first steps using Spring

Tags: spring-boot

tried to follow the Spring Boot [Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).

I used STS-4 IDE with *Import Spring Getting Started Content*, getting the project *gs-consuming-rest-complete*.

*mvn test* failed with a big stack dump followed by the lines

```
... <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.consumingrest.ConsumingRestApplicationTest
[ERROR] contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.113 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 
404 Not Found: [404 Not Found: Requested route ('gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io') does not exist.
]
```

To me it looks like the URL *https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random* is not up. Hence, I cannot use that example. Am I right here or did I do some beginners failure?

[here](https://pastebin.com/pDuig5gV) I have put the full console output.

Comment: Yes, it's down. Best to search for some other tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To me it looks like the URL https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random is not up*

Yes you are right, the URL is returning 404.

As per [article's discuss comment section](https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/21/building-a-restful-quotation-service-with-spring) it's confirmed that there are some issues with this website.